# how to handle db connectivity of couchdb with gwt?

Tags: gwt, couchdb

I am new to couchdb and I want to learn about how to connect the couchdb in our gwt server side program. till now, I tried to work on its gui to create database add documents and add fields to it.but i am not able to use it in program. what exactly the way to do it..
I tried some code but didn't got it.

Answer (score 1):

In your GWT you should have something like this in your server. Besides it you should have your DAO for your Entities (`erktorp` takes place here) and your mechanism for connecting GWT's client with the server (for example `RequestFactory`).

```
  //Object of your own related with couch db management
  CouchDbAccess couchDbAccess = null;

  @Inject
  public CouchDbManagement(String ddbbUrl, String ddbbName) throws IOException {
    HttpClient httpClient;
    Builder b;
    try {
      b = new StdHttpClient.Builder().url(ddbbUrl);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      ddbbUrl = "http://admin:sa@localhost:5984";
      b = new StdHttpClient.Builder();
    }

    b.socketTimeout(60000);

    String user = getUserFrom(ddbbUrl);
    String pass = getPassFrom(ddbbUrl);
    b.username(user).password(pass);

    httpClient = b.build();


    CouchDbInstance dbInstance = new StdCouchDbInstance(httpClient);
    if (initialize && dbInstance.getAllDatabases().contains(ddbbName)) {
      dbInstance.deleteDatabase(ddbbName);
      dbInstance = new StdCouchDbInstance(httpClient);
    }

    //If you want Lucene, here is the place

    db.createDatabaseIfNotExists();
    new IndexUploader().updateSearchFunctionIfNecessary(db, ...);
    new IndexUploader().updateSearchFunctionIfNecessary(db, ...);

    URI dbURI = URI.prototype(DbPath.fromString(ddbbName).getPath());
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(dbInstance.getConnection());

    couchDbAccess = new CouchDbAccess(db, dbURI, restTemplate);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couchdb has a restful interface to it's api. Everything is available via url's like

`http://localhost:5984/db_name/doc_name`

In fact the entire http api is [documented in the wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Complete_HTTP_API_Reference). Now I am not familiar with gwt but every framework has `http` libraries and you can use those libraries to make calls to couchdb http endpoints.

A quick google search gave me [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/DevGuideHttpRequests) resource which may guide you on how to create http requests through gwt.